# Moodle local plugin wont update after version change

Tags: php, moodle

So my Problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143727/moodle-event-observer-not-triggered-in-local-plugin). But with my problem it's not a structure problem. I installed the plugin and it didn't work. I updated the version number because at first I forgot to do it. And now after going back to the main page it wont even trigger the update process. Any ideas what could be wrong? I can see the plugins in the plugin overview but no setting nothing. I tried to debug with prints but that didn't help me at all. It just shows that the functions are not entered.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello there. There may be several issues causing this.
The first coming to mind is that you did an upgrade of a table (db/upgrade.php) and typed a wrong new version number.
You can also check the current version number of your plugin and the one registered in your moodle table mdl_config_plugins with this query SELECT x.* FROM moodle.mdl_config_plugins x where name like '%version%' and plugin = 'yourpluginname'

Comment: @Veterini Thanks for your response! I forgot to come back to this question. It actually turned out to be a structural problem. Just somewhere else. Im going to close this question now.